# How to animate circle on canvas when using Android Canvas.drawCircle()

Tags: android

I am trying to animate a circle that is drawn onto a canvas:

```
Paint pCirclePink = new Paint();

pCirclePink.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

pCirclePink.setAntiAlias(true);

if (userPlaceBeacon != null){

c.drawCircle((float) userPlaceBeacon.getPlacement_x() + offsetX, (float) userPlaceBeacon.getPlacement_y() + offsetY, 30, pCirclePink);

Bitmap bmpUserDestination = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableUserMarker).getBitmap();

bmpUserDestination = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpUserDestination, 28, 28, false);

c.drawBitmap(bmpUserDestination, (float) userPlaceBeacon.getPlacement_x() + offsetX - 14, (float) userPlaceBeacon.getPlacement_y() + offsetY - 14, null);

}

c.save();
```

When 'c.drawCircle' is called, I want the circle to have a pulse animation.

The circle shows the users current location on a panable map (which is a Bitmap that is injected using the Glide library).

I am having trouble because most libraries/methods I find online all derive from a View or ViewGroup class; whereas I am trying to draw onto an BitMap that is pan-able and scalable.

Here is more of the code I am working with:

[image: Here is more of the code I am working with.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1) You can create your own custom view by extending View class and draw circle in onDraw(Canvas canvas) method. To imitate a pulse animation you have to call postInvalidate method to force view call onDraw(Canvas canvas) method again and again and draw your increased or decreased circle.

2) You can use simple scale animation